# Why do I keep getting a missing semicolon error when it is clearly right there on my constructor?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secureInput: !(props.inputType === "text" || props.inputType === "email")
    };
  }
```

Am I missing something in this? I keep getting a missing semicolon error
[image]

Comment: What do you mean - "missing semicolon error". JS works without semicolons. Can you share the exact error message

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code? You might be getting that from somewhere else?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: looks like you're trying to declare a `constructor` outside a class - but you can't do that. It needs to be inside a `class` declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is that you're placing your constructor in the wrong part.

You must place your constructor on the root level of your class. 
Take the following examples

```
❌
class Abc ... {
  render() {
    const a = ...
    const b = ...
    constructor() {
      ...
    };
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, the right way to do it:

```
✔️
class Abc ... {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
  
  render() {
    const a = ...
    const b = ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variables in a class level. You can either move them out of the class, or define them as class properties.

```js
const inputColor = textColor;
// ...

class InputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secureInput: !(props.inputType === "text" || props.inputType === "email")
    };
  }

  // ...
}
```

or

```js
class InputField extends Component {
  inputColor = textColor;
  // ...
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secureInput: !(props.inputType === "text" || props.inputType === "email")
    };
  }

 // ...
}
```